# AccountContactRelation object trigger executes while updating contact record

Tags: trigger

I am trying to update contact record which is executing a trigger code on AccountContactRelation object. Is it part of Salesforce functionality? If yes, how can I bypass the accountcontactrelation trigger code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AccountContactRelation` (ACR for short) is a standard SObject that becomes available when you enable the "Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts" feature (Setup menu, "Platform Tools" section -> Feature Settings -> Sales -> Accounts -> Account Settings).

Any triggers on any SObject should be ones introduced by you (your team/company) or through packages that you've installed. I don't think there are any "standard triggers". So the question of "can I bypass it?" boils down to "Did you explicitly write triggers in a way that allows you to prevent the trigger from doing any real work?"

Even if you can bypass a trigger's work, whether or not you *should* do that is another question entirely. If you don't know what it's doing, or if it's not causing you any problems, then the answer to that is most likely "no, don't mess with stuff that you don't understand and/or isn't causing problems".

+edit:
One thing I forgot about ACRs is that enabling the feature does come with some trigger-like behavior.

I say "trigger-like", because it happens on some changes to Contacts, but it doesn't show up as a trigger when you look at Contact/ACR/Account in the object manager and I don't believe that it really appears in debug logs.

When you set or change the `AccountId` on a Contact (on insert or update), Salesforce will automatically create an ACR record for that relationship if it doesn't already exist. The `IsDirect` checkbox is also set for the ACR where the ACR's AccountId matches the Contact's AccountId. I do not know if this is done by this trigger-like behavior as well or if it's simply a formula field in the background. At any rate, this behavior cannot be disabled (or otherwise bypassed).

Comment: "Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts" setting is enabled for a use case using the setting as you mentioned first. I have written a trigger on AccountContactRelation sObject for some validation. When I am trying to update the only contact record from screen, system is executing trigger on AccountContactRelation sObject. Is it a default behaviour of AccountContactRelation that it gets executed everytime contact record updates? If yes, then how can I by-pass (using some check from record) the condition in trigger which is causing to save contact record?